# App Engine URL mapping

Tags: google-app-engine, url-mapping

From http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html

> Tip: App Engine routes requests to
>   Python scripts based on the URL and
>   mappings specified in the
>   application's app.yaml file. A webapp
>   WSGIApplication further maps specific
>   URL paths to request handlers. **How
>   you use both mappings is up to you:
>   You could have all non-static URLs go
>   to a single Python script, and have
>   the script dispatch all dynamic URLs
>   to handlers. Or, you can group
>   functionality into multiple WSGI
>   applications run by different scripts,
>   and use app.yaml to map the
>   appropriate URLs to the appropriate
>   applications.**

My question is: Which is better/faster/more efficient (app.yaml mapping to multiple apps?) or if there is no performance difference, which would you use and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine: Handlers and WSGI urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335446/google-app-engine-handlers-and-wsgi-urls)

Comment: yeah I saw that post while searching but wasn't sure if it was the same w/o needing to use authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no performance difference worth considering. The pattern most people use is to have a single handler script (with a single mapping in app.yaml) per logical 'application' inside your webapp. In many apps, that translates to just one handler, or one for the main site plus another for the admin functionality.

Comment: thx for the answer.  will prob use app.yaml to map to separate main content and comment section scripts.